# Tick() method error when I run it. HELP!

Tags: java

Okay so I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at basic.game.here.Game.tick(Game.java:71)
at basic.game.here.Game.run(Game.java:54)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the code it says the error relates to:

```
package basic.game.here;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import basic.game.here.tiles.Ground;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WIDTH = 960, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

private Thread thread;

private boolean running = false;

private int FPS = 0;

private World world;
private Player player;

public Game(){
    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "BASIC", this);

    world = new World();

    player = new Player(500, 200);

}

public synchronized void start(){
    thread = new Thread(this);
    running = true;
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    try{
        thread.join();
        running = false;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {
    long lastTimeChecked = System.nanoTime();
    int frames = 0;
    while(running){
        tick();
        render();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(6);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        frames++;
        if(System.nanoTime() - lastTimeChecked >= 1000000000){
            FPS = frames;
            frames = 0;
            lastTimeChecked = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
}

private void tick() {
    player.tick();
}

private void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 18));
    g.drawString("" + FPS, 5, 20);

    //g.drawString("(" + player.x + ", " + player.y + ")", 5, 40);

    world.render(g);
    player.render(g);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Game();
}

}
```

Here is the player class because I think it is related to this:

```
package basic.game.here;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Player {

private int x, y;

public Player(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void tick(){

}

public void render(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 16, 16);
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crash message indicates that `Game.tick()` is the source of the null reference exception:

```
>            Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException at
> -- see --> basic.game.here.Game.tick(Game.java:71)
```

`Game.tick()` itself contains nothing but a call to `player.tick()`, so `player` is probably null. The player tick function is empty, so even if there were some kind of callstack trimming due to inlining, the only thing that *can* be null in this code is `player`.

Put a breakpoint on the `player.tick()` call in `Game.tick()` and verify that player is non-null; you *do* initialize it in the `Game` constructor, but *after* you pass the game to the window. Perhaps the window class is calling `run`, and thus `tick()` before you have executed the line of code that initializes the player.

You could also try moving the `player = new Player...` line up above the `new Window...` line.

Comment: Okay I moved player = new player above new Window because the run method is called in the Window class. Thank you for solving this for me! It has been very annoying to me.